# Passing javascript variable to php variable on the same page concept

Tags: javascript, php

need your advice, I have a form with some many fields, i use it to post to database, it's simply if i post it one by one. But it's so heavy if we have thousands data to post. i wanna post it cumulatively.

For now i use javascript, i add it to an array for temporary storage then show it with table under form. i want to use this array then post it into array variable of PHP.  Then i can post to database. But i  don't know how to do it if it on the same page. Because javascript is client side, and PHP is server side.

Is there any idea?

EDITED :
this my code, I have not made it in the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<label>Fruit Name</label> :<br>
<input type="text" id="text1"/><br>
<label>Nominal</label> :<br>
<input type="text" id="text2"/><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button><button onclick="tableCreate()">Add</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<?php $a = array(); ?>
<script>
    var products = [];

    function myFunction() {
        var text1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
        var text2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;

        var temp = text1 + "-" + text2;

        products.push(temp);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = products;
    }


</script>
<hr>
<form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="test" value="Test">Save</button>
</form>

<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['test'])){

    // get array products from javascript, isn't possible?

 }
?>

</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can use ajax to post data

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of php for submitting a form and inserting the record to database.Write php script on the same page which will be executed on form post.

Save the following code snippet to a php file name as currentPhpFileName.php and execute it over localhost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="currentPhpFileName.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fieldName1" value="testValue1" />
<input type="text" name="fieldName2" value="testValue2" />
<button type="submit" name="test" value="Test">Save</button>
</form>
<?php 
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
 {      
   print_r($_POST['fieldName1']);
   print_r($_POST['fieldName2']);
  foreach($_POST as $value)
  {
    print_r($value);  
    //database connection
    //logic to insert records into database
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i mean, is there way to solve my case? for the recent, my plan, i submit it to array using java script, then i want to passing it into PHP variable on the same page, then i can using this array for looping and post it into database.. but i don't know how to do, when we use on the same page, it's impossible because java script and php script is different side. is there any ways guys?

Comment: i have tried your tips, and yeah, it's usefull.. But when we want to post 3 different inputs, and before that, our 3 different inputs have in an array. How do we post in database? is PHP can do that?

thanks for reply..

Comment: For that you need to use php sql database connection.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp Try it out and come with new question if you face any issues.